# Compass with multiple input/output folders

Tags: compass-sass

I'd like to compile/watch Compass/SCSS files, spread over multiple folders, in one command. As far as I know there is no way to configure multiple SCSS folders, coupled with separate CSS output folders.

`add_import_path` is almost what I need, but I don't see a way to set `sass_dir` per import path.

Is there a way to do this?
[This Quora answer](http://www.quora.com/Compass-stylesheet/How-to-monitor-multiple-directories-in-a-project) says there is none, but I still have my hopes up :)

---

Update: Example directory structure:

- users/user1/css/ <- scss directory
- users/user1/css/generated/ <- generated css directory
- users/user2/css/
- users/user2/css/generated/
- themes/theme1/css/
- themes/theme1/css/generated/
- themes/theme2/css/
- themes/theme2/css/generated/

Comment: Certainly doable using a task runner like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). If you can add some detail like the directory tree and what things you want to compile and where they should end up, I'll whip up a sample gruntfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you want to compile all these scattered SASS files in one compiled CSS. If that's the case I'm afraid I don't know how to help you.

However, if you want multiple files one possible solution is to use Rake.

What about wrapping all the watch commands you need in one Rake task, and then executing such task in order to get them running at once.

#### Rakefile

```rb
namespace :stylesheets do
  desc 'Watches dynamic stylesheets for user 1 to compile changes'
  task :watch_user1 do
    puts 'Watching first set of stylesheets...'
    system 'compass watch --sass-dir users/user1/css --css-dir users/user1/css/generated -c config/compass.rb'
  end

  desc 'Watches dynamic stylesheets for user 2 to compile changes'
  task :watch_user2 do
    puts 'Watching second set of stylesheets...'
     system 'compass watch --sass-dir users/user2/css --css-dir users/user2/css/generated -c config/compass.rb'
  end
  desc 'Watches dynamic stylesheet all to compile changes'

  multitask watch_all: ['stylesheets:watch_user1', 'stylesheets:watch_user2'] do
    puts 'watching all...'
  end
end
```

Then you just run the multi task `rake stylesheets:watch_all` and all the sub tasks are issued running their commands in threads.

This rake tasks can be heavily improved because they are repetitive and through some conventions you could even configure it through .yml files, but hopefully will give you ideas of what you can do with Rake.

Here some more info on [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) and a [nice tutorial about writing rake tasks](http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial)

Cheers!

Comment: Updated the question. This looks nice, even though I have close to no Ruby experience. Is `system` an asynchronous call?

Comment: Hi @Znarkus I updated the answer, because my assumption was wrong. Thanks for clarifying the example.
  
  The Ruby Kernel#system method is not async. But you can always split what you need to do into multiple tasks and build them in paralel using Rake's multitask which uses Threads.

  See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pickup single scss filepath, from command line.

Example of **prodConfig.rb**:

```
cid = ARGV[0] || "default"
cid = cid.sub(/\.scss$/,'').sub(/^.*\//,'')
puts "making with cid="+cid
http_path ="/fcss/" + cid + "/"
css_dir = "public/fcss/"+cid
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "sass/img"
generated_images_dir="public/fcss/"+cid+"/img"
http_images_path="/fcss/"+cid+"/img/"
output_style = :expanded #: :compressed
```

Run "compass compile -c sass/prodConfig.rb sass/dynamic/**xxx**.scss"

Now we have "**xxx**" at prodConfig.rb in variable **cid**